# C define Macro with same name in different header?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

Is that possible to define macros with same name in different header files
For example, in a header file a.h and b.h
we both define macros with same identifier

Comment: As long as both headers will never be included in the same translation unit and doesn't change any definitions that would be used in multiple places, it's *legal*, although it sounds like a pretty bad idea... Depends exactly what you are trying to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

As long as both files are not included together, it would have no trouble at all.
In case you wanna include both files, make sure you undef this duplicate symbol before including second file.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't include both a.h and b.h simultaneously in the same file you are all good. The compiler wouldn't even complain. 
If you indeed declare both include in the same file the compiler will raise a Warning and will take the value of the latest include declared, as the compiler has to make a choice.
EG :

`#define foo 1` (a.h)

`#define foo 2` (b.h)

In foo.c :

```
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"
```

foo will give the value of 2 as it is included last.

If you want to still use it don't forget to **undef** one of the duplicate.

But this manipulation is **very bad** as your code will become **less readable** it ***will have undefined behaviour*** and they are chances you ll **even get lost in your own code**.

Comment: Even if you don't include both in the same translation unit, there are cases that can break, for instance an `inline` function whose definition changes based on this macro, being included in two translation units with different versions of the macro.

Comment: @BoBTFish - If that function and the macro aren't organized as a single cohesive piece of code (as much as possible, anyway), then this code base has bigger problems.

Comment: @StoryTeller I 100% agree, but based on the question it sounds like a possibility.

Comment: This is wrong, the C standard says you must not redefine a macro with a differente replacement list without undef, otherwise the behaviour is undefined. It is only ok to have `#define foo 1` followed by `#define foo 1`, but not `#define foo 2`

Comment: He didn't asked for the undef tag he asks if declaring two Macros with the same name is possible (not correct, but possible) and yes it is. The answer is given and tested, don't spoil him let him fetch for its own asnwers.

Comment: If the C standard says something shall not be done, claiming that it is "possible" or that "some behaviour is expected" is outright wrong, especially since the OP didn't mention what compiler they're using.